# Which Facebook APIs can be used to programatically post a message?

Tags: facebook

I have an application that allows a user to post messages. I'd like to give an option to users to propagate the same posts on their Facebook wall / status. Which Facebook APIs can I leverage, including the ones that are need to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's JS API (useful for client-side), the new Graph API, or the old REST API. Facebook has extensive documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path is probably to use the Facebook.streamPublish() function through the FBJS API.

You can also use streamPublish() through direct Facebook API calls, but you need extended permissions. Using FBJS, Facebook will display their own prompt to the user, so you do not need extended permissions.